# How to insert form data in wordpress database using php and mysql code

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert some values inside the  wp database from the form but it's not getting inserted.  your help would be appreciated very much.

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>




<?php 
global $wpdb; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "user2"; 
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert using this code :

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
global $wpdb; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['name ']) && isset($_POST['email '])) {
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "user2"; 
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email ) );
}
else{
echo "No parameter";exit;
}
} ?>
```

**OR You can try core php**

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
global $wpdb; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "user2"; 

        $sql="insert into '$table_name' table (name,email)values('$name','$email')";
        mysql_query($sql);


} ?>
```

Comment: thanks Vasim. i tried your script but its not inserting data into wp database

Comment: still not inserted data into wp databse

Comment: i dont get any error msg. but data table is still null

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO "+$table_name+"   (`name`,`email`)  values ($name, $email)";

Comment: no input value inserted in the table in wp database using this line of code

Comment: echo $sql; print this

Comment: can we move in chat room?

Comment: can we use simple sql

Comment: how to write it in wordpress?

Comment: Can you please tell me where you put this file?

Comment: <?php
/*
Template Name: wp insert data
*/

?>

<form method="post" action=""> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
global $wpdb; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['name ']) && isset($_POST['email '])) {
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "user2"; 
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email ) );
}
else{
echo "No parameter";exit;
}
} 

?>

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: add in your wp_config file

Comment: instead. in /home/teacherscafe/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3624

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use